# Invoke Metro web service from bpel

Tags: web-services, cxf, bpel, java-metro-framework

I tried to invoke a simple web service (based on Metro stack, deployed on Tomcat 7) from a bpel process and i have a problem.

When i test this web service with soapui or other similar tool, everything works fine. So the web service is ok. I think that the bpel is also correct.

The bpel process is running in bpel-g, and it is also deployed on the same tomcat server. So my question is, if it is posible to invoke a (Metro) web service from a bpel-g engine (which is build uppon cfx stack).

If its not possible, should i just build my web services uppon apache cxf, and it will work?

EDIT:
So, as i said the web service is running on metro stack in a tomcat 7 server. The bpel-g-5.3 is deployed on another tomcat server. When i try to invoke the web service from the process i get the following stacktrace:

```
 org.activebpel.rt.AeException logError SEVERE: no protocol:
    java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at org.activebpel.rt.axis.bpel.AeAxisInvokeHandler.setTargetAddress    (AeAxisInvokeHandler.java:334) 
    org.activebpel.rt.axis.bpel.AeAxisInvokeHandler.createCall        (AeAxisInvokeHandler.java:177)
    ...
```

My bpel process:

```
    <!-- SampleProcessFile BPEL Process [Generated by the Eclipse BPEL Designer] -->
<!-- Date: Fri Mar 01 17:47:28 CET 2013 -->
<bpel:process name="SampleProcessFile"
         targetNamespace="http://Sample"
         suppressJoinFailure="yes"
         xmlns:tns="http://Sample"
         xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
         xmlns:ns="http://server/">

    <!-- Import the client WSDL -->
    <bpel:import namespace="http://server/" location="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication10/NewWebService?wsdl" importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"></bpel:import>
    <bpel:import location="SampleProcessFileArtifacts.wsdl" namespace="http://Sample" 
            importType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" />

    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <!-- PARTNERLINKS                                                      -->
    <!-- List of services participating in this BPEL process               -->
    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <bpel:partnerLinks>
        <!-- The 'client' role represents the requester of this service. -->
        <bpel:partnerLink name="client"
                     partnerLinkType="tns:SampleProcessFile"
                     myRole="SampleProcessFileProvider"
                     />
        <bpel:partnerLink name="SamplePL" partnerLinkType="tns:SamplePLT" partnerRole="InBound"></bpel:partnerLink>
    </bpel:partnerLinks>

    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <!-- VARIABLES                                                         -->
    <!-- List of messages and XML documents used within this BPEL process  -->
    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <bpel:variables>
        <!-- Reference to the message passed as input during initiation -->
        <bpel:variable name="input"
                  messageType="tns:SampleProcessFileRequestMessage"/>

        <!-- 
          Reference to the message that will be returned to the requester
          -->
        <bpel:variable name="output"
                  messageType="tns:SampleProcessFileResponseMessage"/>
        <bpel:variable name="SamplePLResponse" messageType="ns:helloResponse"></bpel:variable>
        <bpel:variable name="SamplePLRequest" messageType="ns:hello"></bpel:variable>
    </bpel:variables>

    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <!-- ORCHESTRATION LOGIC                                               -->
    <!-- Set of activities coordinating the flow of messages across the    -->
    <!-- services integrated within this business process                  -->
    <!-- ================================================================= -->         
    <bpel:sequence name="main">

        <!-- Receive input from requester. 
             Note: This maps to operation defined in SampleProcessFile.wsdl 
             -->
        <bpel:receive name="receiveInput" partnerLink="client"
                 portType="tns:SampleProcessFile"
                 operation="process" variable="input"
                 createInstance="yes"/>

        <!-- Generate reply to synchronous request -->
        <bpel:assign validate="no" name="Assign">
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from><bpel:literal><tns:hello xmlns:tns="http://server/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <name>name</name>
</tns:hello>
</bpel:literal></bpel:from>
                <bpel:to variable="SamplePLRequest" part="parameters"></bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from part="payload" variable="input">
                    <bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[tns:input]]></bpel:query>
                </bpel:from>
                <bpel:to part="parameters" variable="SamplePLRequest">
                    <bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[name]]></bpel:query>
                </bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
        </bpel:assign>
        <bpel:invoke name="Invoke" partnerLink="SamplePL" operation="hello" portType="ns:NewWebService" inputVariable="SamplePLRequest" outputVariable="SamplePLResponse"></bpel:invoke>
        <bpel:assign validate="no" name="Assign1">
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from><bpel:literal><tns:SampleProcessFileResponse xmlns:tns="http://Sample" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <tns:result>tns:result</tns:result>
</tns:SampleProcessFileResponse>
</bpel:literal></bpel:from>
                <bpel:to variable="output" part="payload"></bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
            <bpel:copy>
                <bpel:from part="parameters" variable="SamplePLResponse">
                    <bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[return]]></bpel:query>
                </bpel:from>
                <bpel:to part="payload" variable="output">
                    <bpel:query queryLanguage="urn:oasis:names:tc:wsbpel:2.0:sublang:xpath1.0"><![CDATA[tns:result]]></bpel:query>
                </bpel:to>
            </bpel:copy>
        </bpel:assign>
        <bpel:reply name="replyOutput" 
               partnerLink="client"
               portType="tns:SampleProcessFile"
               operation="process" 
               variable="output"
               />
    </bpel:sequence>
</bpel:process>
```

and finally the wsdl of the web service:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><!-- Published by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2-hudson-740-. --><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2-hudson-740-. --><definitions xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://server/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="http://server/" name="NewWebService">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://server/" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication10/NewWebService?xsd=1" />
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="hello">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:hello" />
</message>
<message name="helloResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:helloResponse" />
</message>
<portType name="NewWebService">
<operation name="hello">
<input wsam:Action="http://server/NewWebService/helloRequest" message="tns:hello" />
<output wsam:Action="http://server/NewWebService/helloResponse" message="tns:helloResponse" />
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="NewWebServicePortBinding" type="tns:NewWebService">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document" />
<operation name="hello">
<soap:operation soapAction="" />
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" />
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="NewWebService">
<port name="NewWebServicePort" binding="tns:NewWebServicePortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/WebApplication10/NewWebService" />
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

EDIT2: I tried the same bpel process, invoking the same web service on jboss app server with riftsaw (which is built uppon ODE) and on cxf stack and its working, so the process and the service is correct. I guess there are some compatibility issues between bpel-g and metro.

Comment: Metro and bpel-g should be able to communicate. Maybe there is an error in the process? What exactly is your problem (error message, etc.)? How does the WSDL file of the service look like? How does the invoke activity look like?